# How come DataFrame.to_dict returns different values on invocations?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` which seems to misbehave (?) in the following way:

```
>>> a=z.to_dict(orient='records')
>>> b=z.to_dict(orient='records')
>>> a1=json.dumps(a)
>>> b1=json.dumps(b)
>>> a1 == b1
True
>>> a == b
False # <<<===== WHAT?!!!
>>> for i in xrange(z.shape[0]):
      print i, a[i] == b[i]
0 True
...
9 True
10 True
11 True
12 False
13 True
14 True
...
20 True
21 False
22 True
...
29 False
30 True
...
40 True
41 True
42 False
43 True
44 True
...
50 False
51 True
52 False
...
```

What does this mean?!

Comment: What's `a[12]` and `b[12]`?

Comment: Perchance, is it `NaN`? Because that will always return `False` for `==`. However, however, the JSON string representations will be equal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juanpa.arrivlllaga nailed it.  In a float dataframe, when a cell is `np.nan` `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to `False`

```
z = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10), columns=list('abcdefghij'))
z
```

[image]

```
a=z.to_dict(orient='records')
b=z.to_dict(orient='records')
a1=json.dumps(a)
b1=json.dumps(b)

a == b

True

a1 == b1

True
```

---

```
z.loc[5, 'd'] = np.nan
z
```

[image]

```
a=z.to_dict(orient='records')
b=z.to_dict(orient='records')
a1=json.dumps(a)
b1=json.dumps(b)

a == b

True

a1 == b1

False
```